# How to take the root of a complex number when the right side of the equation is zero?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, complex-numbers, polar-coordinates

so I know that when wanting to take the root of the complex number in a case like this

$$z^4=1+\sqrt3i$$

it's really just computing the polar coordinates and finding the solutions for $z_{0}, z_{1},...,z_{3}$ with De Moivre's formula etc.

but when we have something like this instead...

$$z^7+7i=0$$

how am I supposed to compute the $\Re$ and $\Im$ parts of this? With the first exercise I can easily come up with the polar form, but the second one is just horrendous. I don't see where that number has its real and imaginary parts which makes computing $r$ and especially the angle $\varphi$ a mystery.

I would really appreciate any help ;-; thank you so much!!

Comment: Ouch ! $z^7=-7i$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\theta = (-\pi/2) \implies -i = e^{i\theta} \implies
z^7 = -7i = 7e^{i\theta}$.

Therefore, one of the roots of the equation is 
$z_r = (7)^{(1/7)}e^{i(\theta/7)}.$

Having found one of the roots, you find all 7 roots, by computing 
$w_k = z_r \times z_k : k \in \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ 
where $z_k$ is the $k$-th root of $z^7 = 1 \implies $ 
$z_k = e^{(i2k\pi/7)}.$

**Edit**
To elaborate:

- $e^{i\theta}$ is shorthand for $[\cos(\theta) + i\sin(\theta)].$
- Although (for example) $\cos(-\pi/14)$ is probably expressible by radicals, this is almost certainly **not** the point of the problem.  Therefore, expressing the roots by their polar coordinates should be fine.

Comment: Thank you too! But how do I get to $\theta$ when I only have this table here [link](https://imgur.com/a/hs38fHq) in mind? I can't use a calculator in the exam. I know how to handle the polar circle in the context of the values of the ones given in the table but I'm not sure what to do when it's $-\arccos(7)$ (since $\frac{x}{r} = \frac{0}{7})$

Comment: @LinShao When complex numbers are expressed in  Cartesian coordinates as $z = (x + iy)$ then you have that $(-i) = [0 + i(-1)].$  At this point, you are supposed to recognize that on the unit circle, the angle associated with $(x,y) = (0,-1)$ is $(-90^\circ) = (-\pi/2).$

Comment: @LinShao Also, please re-read my answer.  I emphasize that the point of the problem is probably **not** to express (for example) $$[\cos(-\pi/14) + i\sin(-\pi/14)] ~\text{by radicals}.$$  Instead, I would expect your teacher to accept that one of the roots is in fact $$(7)^{(1/7)}e^{(-i\pi/14)}.$$

Comment: so does that mean for any of the axis ends of the unit circle, i.e. $(1,0)$, $(0,1)$, $(-1,0)$, $(0,-1)$, for every $x$ or $y$ that is a natural number in this tuple (or an integer, in the case of -1), it just in the end breaks down to those four cases since we can rotate through the circle an arbitrary amount of n times? i.e. making $(0,-7)$ the $(0,-1)$ edit: and thank you, I will write my teacher a mail :)

Comment: @LinShao I don't understand the comment/question that you are asking.  Please re-phrase your comment/question, perhaps deleting the comment and giving a new one.  Please try to **very carefully elaborate** precisely what you are asking.

Comment: Note: by DeMoivre's theorem, $$\left(e^{i\theta}\right)^n : n \in \mathbb{Z^+} = e^{in\theta}.$$

Comment: I'm really sorry, I'm really still a beginner so all these math notations are quite difficult to explain :( so, as you said, the axes of the unit circle are four tuples of $(x,y)$ as seen here [link](https://imgur.com/a/5MeFt7O). What I'm trying to ask is if we have a complex number like the one in question, where either $\Re$ or $\Im$ is a zero, and the other respective part is $\in{\mathbb N}$ or $\in{\mathbb Z}$, can we just $mod$ that latter number given DeMoivre's clock arithmetic because we basically just rotate around the unit circle. Making $(0,-7)$ the $(0,-1)$ because we rotate 7x

Comment: or, in other words: where the latter part (n) is $\in{\mathbb Z^+}$ like the theorem says.

Comment: The later portion of your last comment is garbled, so I will take a guess at answering it.  From the link that you provided, you  know that $$[0 + i(-1)] = [\cos(3\pi/2) + i\sin(3\pi/2)] = [\cos(-\pi/2) + i\sin(-\pi/2)] = e^{(-i\pi/2)}.$$  Therefore, $$-7i = 7(-i) = 7[0 + i(-1)] = 7e^{(-i\pi/2)}.$$  Does this answer your question?

Comment: basically yes! thanks a lot and sorry again! :))

Answer (score 1):

You can write it as $$z^7 = -7 \iota$$and then take modulus to get $r^7 = 7$

Here $\iota = \sqrt{-1}$

Comment: So I have  thought of this but I was sure it would be wrong!... normally one would end up with this table [lin](https://imgur.com/a/hs38fHq) I want to compute this without the use of a calculator. How could I find the corresponding angle to $-\arccos{(7)}$ in the polar circle?

Comment: @LinShao I think you misunderstood something there is $r^7$ also so you won't get $\arccos(7)$ but you will get an equation as $\cis(7\theta) = -i$

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Simply rearrange into the form
$$z^7=-7i$$
We can let $z=r(\cos(\theta+2k\pi)+i\sin(\theta+2k\pi))$ and proceed like usual. If you need any more help please don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Please refer to the comment for the post above. I have thought of this but I'm not quite sure how to see the $-\arccos{(7)}$ in the context of the polar circle.

Comment: @LinShao I think you've made a mistake; there is no angle $-\arccos 7$, there is an angle $-\pi/14$ though.